# Assigning parameters or constraints to a model?

Tags: add-on

I want to build model with certain parameters and constraints.

For example, I built a tissue box model in blender. I then want to assign parameter name `hole width` and `hole length` such that when I tweak these parameter, the hole of tissue box will resize automatically according to the parameters.

I am not sure if blender (and general 3d software) support this figure.

Comment: If you want to create your own addon then look at the [archimesh addon](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BA/browse/master/archimesh/) which was added to the standard addons in 2.78, it provides parametric building objects. A more end user oriented option would be the [sverchok](https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok) addon.

Comment: You could look into procedural modelling with drivers similar to [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ILT2KRF0r58)

Answer (score 1):

From version 2.93 onward, these types of parameters can be exposed using *Geometry Nodes*.  The feature is still in development, but it is fairly mature at this point.

You can connect a noodle from the Group Input node to any geometry node input to expose the value in the pane in the modifier stack.

Answer (score 0):

You could add Shape Keys to change the size of things in the object. Also you could try to do it with hook modifiers. Another way to do that thing with the hole you mentioned would be to add a boolean modifier to the main mesh and set it to difference. Then add a Cube (Or whatever the Hole has to be shaped like) and translate it to the correct position. Put the name of the cube in the boolean modifier field and then you can control the hole by scaling that cutout object.

But your task sounds more like a thing to do in scad.